# How to Modify WordPress Default Image Gallery Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I would like to be able to show 5 columns and only 10 images per page for the default WordPress image gallery. Visually I would imagine it to look something like the following:

> columns="5" pagination="10"

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: WP native gallery shortcode does not support a pagination parameter

Answer (score 1):

You could try this plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagination/

It makes a javascript approach to paging.

For my projects i always started to build galleries using custom post types or repeaterfields with acf:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

Wordpress built in gallery function is... well almost unfunctional. :)